# Topologist's Sin Curve: Last Step in Proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Synopsis**

I'm in an undergraduate real analysis course as a freshman, and I'm in the last part of a proof which I'm having trouble on. Before, we start, note the following definition:

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Two open subsets, $U$ and $V$, of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are said to *separate* the set $A$ provided that their intersections with $A$ are both nonempty, $A \cap U \neq \varnothing$ and $A \cap V \neq \varnothing$, are disjoint, $(A \cap U) \cap (A \cap V) = \varnothing$, and their union is all of $A$, $(A \cap U) \cup (A \cap V) = A$.

**Question**

The question states:

Let $K = \{(0,y)|y \in [-1,1]\}$ and let $G = \{(x, \sin(\frac{2\pi}{x})|x \in (0,1]\}$. The union $T = K \cup G$ is the Topologist's Sine Curve. We will show this is connected by contradiction. Assume $T$ is not connected. Let $U$ and $V$ separate $T$. Without loss of generality assume that $V \cap G \neq \varnothing$.

I've already proved most of the steps, and I know that

(a) $K$ is path connected;
(b) $G$ is path connected.;
(c) $G \cap U = \varnothing$ and $G \subset V$.;
(d) $K \cap U \neq \varnothing$ and $K \subset U$.
(e) If $\vec{x} \in K$, then every open ball around $\vec{x}$ must intersect $G$.

Now I am on the last step which is to show that $(T \cap U) \cap (T \cap V) \neq \varnothing$.

**My Attempt**

To start, using the distributive property of unions and intersections, and the fact that since $K \subset U$, $K \cap U = K$ and similarly, that $ G \cap V = G$, I deduced that $$(T \cap U) \cap (T \cap V) = ((K \cup G) \cap U) \cap ((K \cup G) \cap V) = ((K \cap U) \cup (G \cap U)) \cap ((K \cap V) \cup (G \cap V)) =\\ K \cap ((K \cap V) \cup (G \cap V)) = K \cap ((K \cap V) \cup G) = (K \cap V) \cup (K \cap G) = K \cap V.$$ It should also be noted that the third equality utilizes the fact that $G \cap U = \varnothing$ and the sixth utilizes the fact that $K \cap G = \varnothing$. So now I find that all I have to show is $K \cap V \neq \varnothing$ and so I think "this is where part (e) comes into play!" In (e), we essentially showed that $K \subset \text{bd}(G) \subset \text{cl}(G)$ which is the smallest closed set containing $G$. So $K \subset \text{cl}(V)$. But that's not what I want. I want $K \subset V$ so I can show $K \cap V \neq \varnothing$, but $V$ is open, so that idea doesn't really work. Any advice or hints on how to solve this last part?

Comment: This curve is the topologist's *sine*, I think. Topologists are virtuous people so they won't use sin (ok, sorry for that one). Let $x \in K$; then by (d) there is an open ball $B$ around $x$ that is contained in $U$. By (e), $B$ meets $G$ at a point $y$.  So $y \in G \subset V$ and $y \in B \subset U$, so that $y \in (T \cap V) \cap (T\cap U)$ and you are done. A simpler way to see this is to note that $G$ is connected and is dense in $T$. You can show directly from these assumptions that $T$ is connected.

Comment: Thank you for this! I guess I was overcomplicating things.